# Validating form using jquery Ajax MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Up to this point, I’ve been using Microsoft Ajax for updates in my MVC app. I’m now switching to jQuery Ajax in order to standardize my approach.

However, I just realized that the required field in my model for the form did not fire and the user was able to submit the form even though some required fields were left blank.

What is the standard way to handle required fields if I’m handling my ajax functions using jQuery – i.e. I want the unobtrusive to handle my required fields by highlighting them and not allow the submit button to be clicked.

Also, to mention I am getting data-val attributes through the model.

P.S. I’m now using an event handler to detect click event on submit button for the form. In other words, I’m not using @using.Ajax.BeginForm to define my form.

Comment: a side comment, the fact that user was able to submit a form when javascript validation was disabled means that you do not have a server side validation, which is never a good thing

Comment: no, i am not doing serverside validations.
I want to do jquery validations but dont know the way to do that with html.beginform tag

Comment: my point is, whether you do client side validation (in your case jQuery validation) or not, the server side validation must be present at all times.

Comment: You should use DataAnnotations (In ViewModel or model) to ensure that the server validate entries.